# How to add a new field/attribute to each object in the array in pouchDB?

Tags: pouchdb

I've two tables A and B in pouchDB. One column in table A references table B. Assume table A has a1, a2, b1 columns and table B has b1, b2 and b3 columns. I'm retrieving a list of items from A. Here instead of column b1 in table A, I want table B's b2 column. How can I do this in pouchDB.

```
const localDB = new PouchDB('A');
const remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/A');
localDB.find({selector: { "a1": { $eq: "search_value" }}, function (err, results) {
    return results;
});
```

Comment: So you want to update your documents form A and replace b1 by b2?  If so, you should do some sort of "migration". You can basically have a job that queries all documents of A. Then foreach of them, it queries the B document and updates the A document. [PouchDB-migrate](https://github.com/eHealthAfrica/pouchdb-migrate) could be useful in this case.

Comment: @AlexisCôté, I don't want to affect the database. I just want this change locally. And I also don't want to do foreach. Can this be done?

Comment: You can use a view to emit the document linked ([see this wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/EntityRelationship)). For example, you could query for the document A and you would receive as a response two document : one being the document A, the other being the document B. Then, you could modify your document A locally.